# Visual Studio 2015 RC + RequireJS + jQuery

Tags: jquery, requirejs, typescript, visual-studio-cordova

I'm using Visual Studio 2015RC + Cordova CLI 5.1.1 + TypeScript + RequireJS + jQuery .

I'd like to change the location of my jquery.js file from the `scripts` folder to `scripts/lib`.  I added a requirejs.config and changed the jQuery location.

`requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts/lib',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery'
    }
});`

Unfortunately, when I debug using Ripple I get the following error.

`Exception occurred
Message: Exception: Script error for: jquery
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror`

[image]

I'm not sure if this is a problem with RequireJS and jQuery or VS2015RC + Cordova.

Comment: This probably have nothing to do with TypeScript but just a script loading error. Check the console for any error related to the loading or parsing of the jquery file.

Comment: It's definitely a script loading error `404`.  Unfortunately, when I debug in ripple, it's always looking for scripts/jquery.js even though `requirejs.config` was set to use a different location. I created a sample VS2015 Cordova Project to illustrate the problem.  Download files from [https://github.com/dbiele/Testing_CordovaJQueryRequireJSTypeScript](https://github.com/dbiele/Testing_CordovaJQueryRequireJSTypeScript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure if this is a problem with RequireJS and jQuery or VS2015RC + Cordova.

The error is that `jquery` isn't resolving to the `jquery.js` file (an HTTP 404 error). Check the HTTP Get request made by the browser. It will be something like `http://yourapp/scripts/lib/jquery.js`. Make this GET call yourself (open the link in your browser. And based on that fix the config to the correct path to jquery.js file.

Comment: Basart, You're correct about the 404 error. I checked the network log using Chrome and I do see the 404 error. ![image](http://gyazo.com/46b7659549913369a59c710a9bb953b0)However, changes to `requirejs.config({ ...` does not change where the .js file is loading. It's always looking for `http://localhost:4400/scripts/jquery.js`

Comment: I think I found the problem, but I'm still not sure if it's a problem with RequireJS and jQuery or VS2015 + Cordova.  I created a small VS2015 Cordova project with some sample code. I added the code to GitHub for review. If I add a function call to an external module in the data-main js file, it seems to break the `require.config` and require.js only look for `scripts/jquery`.  Take a look at the sample code and try publishing. I included info in the readme.[https://github.com/dbiele/Testing_CordovaJQueryRequireJSTypeScript](https://github.com/dbiele/Testing_CordovaJQueryRequireJSTypeScript)